# Restart playing video in VLC after pausing with skip back 2 seconds

Tags: linux, video, vlc

I am writing notes from video (on `VLC` player on `ubuntu 20.04`), so i play video for 9/10 seconds, and then stop it, take a note, and then resume the video, and then skip back (using SHIFT+left arrow).

since this is a  repeated process, i need one action to Resume AND get back 2/3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds suspiciously like you are performing transcription.

While I have no instant `vlc` quick fix, I did author 2 Transcriber tools for Linux using `vlc` and python3.

`Footswitch2` and `Footswitch2basic`, both of these tools offer the ability to jump back after a pause, for audio or video. The period of time to jump backwards being configurable.

The `Footswitch` in the name refers to a footpedal, for professional transcribers but it will work equally well without one, using either function keys or `Hot Keys` within LibreOffice writer.

Both can be found at SourceForge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/footswitch2/
and
https://sourceforge.net/projects/footswitch2basic/

Both are designed to allow you to operate from within LibreOffice as the editor, with predefined menus and hot-keys.

[image]

I would recommend starting with the `basic` version, as it is stripped of some things that only a profession transcriber would need.